# Homotopy type of hyperplane arrangements intersected with real subspaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, hyperplane-arrangements

The homotopy type, and especially the higher homotopy groups of complement of hyperplane arrangements in $\mathbb{C}^n$ has been extensively studied, for example [Falk and Randell - On the homotopy theory of arrangements](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aspm/1525310067). My situation is slightly different, I can describe it in two ways:

- I have an arrangement $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ of subspaces through the origin, some of codimension $1$, some of codimension $2$, and am interested in the higher homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}^k\setminus A$.
- I have the usual braid arrangement $B$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and a real subspace $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ of dimension $k$ through the origin and am interested in the higher homotopy groups of $(\mathbb{C}^n\setminus B)\cap S$.

Is there any literature about these sorts of spaces? Any idea where to look for results of this kind would be useful!

Comment: Of course, a codimension one real subspace in $A$ causes the complement to be disconnected.  Codimension two real subspaces in some sense generalize codimension one complex subspaces.

Comment: Yes, clear. But is there anything known about the homotopy type of these generalisations?